# Как обработать ответ от newsfeed.get?

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Делаю VKRequest "newsfeed.get", существует ли встроенный в библиотеку метод для обработки response этого запроса?

Comment: [Кликаем](https://vk.com/dev/newsfeed.get) и читаем.

Comment: @Владимир Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.